# knockout.js and listen to check event on checkbox

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

I'm trying to get a function to execute when a checkbox is checked or unchecked to verify all checkboxes are unchecked but it never gets executed.  I assume I'm not doing it correctly.

```
@Html.CheckBox("Subscription", new{ data_bind="disable: Disabled, checked: Checked, click: $parent.allSubscriptionsUnchecked"} )
```

Comment: Definitely not enough info for anyone to give you a good answer without just straight up guessing.

Comment: I don't know if that's a typo but it should be data-bind not with an underscore.

Comment: Must of been enough info, I got my answer.

Comment: @kenny: the underscore is required otherwise it's not valid Razor syntax.  Underscores get rendered as hyphens...

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can add both a `checked` and `click` binding to an input.  However, you would want to `return true;` from the click handler.  This will allow the default action to proceed (the checkbox will be checked/unchecked).

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/cnkVA/

An alternative technique is to push this logic into your view model and subscribe to changes to a boolean observable and execute your action like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/cnkVA/2/

Comment: Thanks I also didnt do the context correct, it should of been $parents[1].

Comment: Thanks for the "return true from click handler" tip!

Comment: 2nd way (subscribe to observable) worked better for me. Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick note, have the checked bind before the click bind otherwise the click bind will fire before the checked and get the wrong value

Comment: @RP Niemeyer If you just want to check one out of a few options in an existing form, how do you do it? Do you just set the value to the one you need (e.g. Option A)? Or do you also have to set it as checked?