# KnockoutJS - How to reassign URL when checkbox is checked vs. unchecked

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to assign an URL in a function everytime a checkbox is checked. But I would also like the URL to be reassigned its initial value when the checkBox is unchecked. I was able to create the code below from the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729060/knockout-js-and-listen-to-check-event-on-checkbox), but the URL is not reassigned when I uncheck the box. Sorry I am new to KnockoutJS and to JavaScript in general.

**HTML**

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox" data-bind="checked:isChecked, click: setUrl">Search Supplier<br>
```

**JS**

```
  searchShippingCodesUrl = '/Parteners/Search';
...
...
ischecked: ko.observable(false),
        setUrl: function () {
                searchShippingCodesUrl = '/Suppliers/Search';
                return true;            
        },
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the click event would fire when checking or unchecking, and your setUrl function doesn't make any check against isChecked to determine what the url should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only use the `click` binding on a checkbox if you need to differentiate whether the checkbox changed state by click vs. by internal setting. The `checked` binding captures the state of the view for you, so you can then work with it in your viewmodel. To take action when it changes, you [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the observable (I borrow the variables here from **dfperry**'s example):

```
ischecked.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    searchShippingCodesUrl = newValue ? supplierSearch : partnerSearch;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check against `isChecked` in your setUrl function to get that toggle effect:

```
var partnerSearch = '/Partners/Search',
    supplierSearch = '/Suppliers/Search';

searchShippingCodesUrl = partnerSearch;

...

ischecked: ko.observable(false),
setUrl: function () {

  searchShippingCodesUrl = (ischecked() ? supplierSearch : partnerSearch);
  return true;            
}
```